# Upgrade 13.04 to 13.10 - packages now unavailable

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades)

> Ubuntu Servers (Recommended) Install update-manager-core if it is not
>   already installed:
>
> sudo apt-get install update-manager-core Launch the upgrade tool:
>
> do-release-upgrade Follow the on-screen instructions.

to upgrade a 13.04 box to 13.10, but I can't even get `update-manager-core` installed at this point. Any ideas how to proceed? I really don't want to rebuild the box from scratch if it can be avoided.

Here's the output from the attempt to install `update-manager-core`

```
nathan@nasty-vault:~$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python3-update-manager
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-update-manager update-manager-core
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
Need to get 39.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python3-update-manager update-manager-core
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main python3-update-manager all 1:0.186.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main update-manager-core all 1:0.186.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/python3-update-manager_0.186.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.186.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've run `apt-get update` which also complains at this point with these types of errors

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

Comment: Note that 13.10 is also EOL, so you'll want to repeat the process above to get to 14.04.

Comment: Hmm, does seem like a dump @saiarcot895, I'll close this one out.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all the repos for 13.04 have been moved to the archive location. You need to add them to the repo before you even do the do-release-upgrade.